# Handle window scroll event in greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, scroll, greasemonkey

I need some advice. I have a web page and want to extend it's functionality with greasemonkey script and firefox.

When page has loaded I need run custom function during user's page scrolling (with mouse whell or scrollbar). I want show some div block when user scrolling down and hide it when he scrolling to the top.

But I met some problem - **I couldn't assign event handler to the onscroll event.** I use next part of the code:

```
function showFixedBlock(){ ... }
function onScrollStart(){ ... showFixedBlock(); ... }
window.onscroll = onScrollStart;
```

I test this piece of code on my test html page and it works, but when I copy it into greasemonkey, script doesn't work.

Should I assign onscroll event handler during page loading? As I know greasemonkey execute it's scripts when page has loaded? Is it the reason of the problem?

Is there some additional requirments to handle 'onscroll' event? How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think that this should work:

```
unsafeWindow.onscroll = onScrollStart;
```

or

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollStart, false);
```

You should really use the latter example.